# How can LL(1) grammars be recursive if an LL(1) parser is non-recursive?

Tags: parsing, recursion, ll-grammar, compiler-construction

An LL(1) parser is a non-recursive predctive parser. Given that, why can LL(1) grammars is be recursive? These seem inconsistent with one another.

Answer (score 2):

I think your confusion stems from the fact that there are several different types of recursion here.

First, there's the fact that any CFG that can generate infinitely many strings - which would be basically any CFG you'd actually want to use in practice - has to involve some amount of recursion. If there isn't any recursion, you only get finitely many strings. So in that sense, there's *CFG recursion*, where there are production rules that lead to the original nonterminal getting produced a second (or third, fourth, etc.) time.

Next, there's the way that the parser is implemented. Some parsers are implemented using recursive descent or recursive backtracking. That's a design decision that's separate from whether the original grammar is recursive. Let's call that *parser recursion.*

Generally speaking, most LL(1) parsers are implemented to not use *parser recursion* and to instead do a bunch of table-based lookups to determine how to drive the parsing. However, many LL(1) grammars have *CFG recursion* in them, but that's separate.

As an example, consider this (very simple) LL(1) grammar:

> A → b | cA

Notice that there's CFG recursion here, since the production A → cA is recursive.

After augmenting the grammar, we get this grammar:

> S → A$
>
> A → b | cA

Here's the LL(1) parsing table for the above grammar:

```
     | b  | c  | $
-----+----+----+---
  S  | A$ | A$ | acc
  A  | b  | cA | -
```

We can use this parsing table to implement a (non-iterative) LL(1) parser by just keeping track of the partial match so far and consulting this table any time we need to predict which production to use.